# Python iterations and row drop

Tags: python, time, iteration

I have a dataframe where each row as a timestamp. The objective is to remove all rows that have less than 12 hours difference.

```
     DateTime
1    2019-01-01 00:15
2    2019-01-01 06:15
3    2019-01-01 11:15
4    2019-01-01 15:15
```

From above, I would drop rows 2 and 3 and take the row 4 as the next base value to continue and so on.

Comment: Take difference between rows in 'hours'. if the difference is less than 12, drop it

Comment: But if I drop i want to keep on having the original value as the reference until the condition is met.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"]) 
df = df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='720Min')).agg({'timestamp' : ['first']})
```

Comment: I get a TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'.
I have the follwing:
input_file = "Data_2019.CSV"
df = pd.read_csv(input_file)  # Dataframe specification
df = df.sort_values(by=['MovementDateTime'])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='MovementDateTime', freq='720Min')).agg({'MovementDateTime': ['first']}

Comment: convert the column into datetime then apply groupby. df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])

Comment: Thanks @phoenix. Can you just help e with one last thing. If i want to have additional columns from original df how can I have them?

Comment: @Eduardo ".agg({'xcolumn' : ['min'], 'ycolumn' : ['max'], ....]})" similarly u can add more columns..u can use 'max', 'min', 'first', 'last', 'mean', 'median' etc to extract the column value

Answer (score 0):

First of all, convert your string data to DateTime:

```py
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateTime"])
```

Then use `groupby()` with `pd.Grouper()`:

```py
df2 = df1.groupby(
    pd.Grouper(key="DateTime", freq="720Min"),
).agg({"DateTime": ["first"]})
```